# Getting password in string format directly from JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, passwords, jpasswordfield

I was taking input from a password field using JPasswordField. Here is the code snippet:

```
JPasswordField enterNewPassword = new JPasswordField ();
enterNewPassword.setBounds( 150,70,100,20);
String password = String.valueOf(enterNewPassword.getPassword());
```

The above code gives me the password as string after adding the function valueOf.
Is there any other way to retrieve the password as string directly?

Comment: A password should never be turned into a `String` as that becomes insecure.

Comment: I agree to that.  But in this case, she has to get the exact password any way.  Probably she will apply a hash function before storing the password in database.  So she wants to remove the intermediate step of  using the String.valueOf(). In all cases she will have access to the raw password inside the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you  create a JTextField and it should point to a JPasswordField.

So use this:

```
 JTextField   enterNewPassword = new JPasswordField();
```

This will hide the text input and will automatically convert the password to plain string also. No conversion is required

Comment: what happens if you use `JPasswordField enterNewPassword = new JPasswordField();` - should it have a different behavior (despite getting a deprecation warning)?

Comment: You will get the password in text and no need to convert it.  I am using this for sometime without any issue. JTextField is the superclass of JPasswordField.  If you debug the code in any IDE you can see the difference.  I was facing the same problem. In case of JPasswordField the input is changed and I had no idea why password plian text was changed.  Then I started using JTextField as the base class.  I do not know the exact reason.

Comment: If we use any String function like String.valueOf() or new String (), in all cases a string object will be generated. So how do we get the password from the login screen. Finally we have to get the password and convert it to MD5 or SHA. What will be the safest way to do that?

Comment: the same happens with the code I posted! `JPassword.getText()` it the exact same method that is called when using your code (you known, inheritance, method overriding and such) (BTW your code is not using `JTextField`, it is still an instance of `JPasswordField`)